# Monotonicity of the Jensen-Shannon divergence

Tags: probability-distributions, information-theory, information-geometry

Let $\text{JSD}(P\mid\mid Q)$ be the Jensen-Shannon divergence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen-Shannon_divergence) between two probability distributions $P$ and $Q$.

**Question**: Is $\text{JSD}(P\mid\mid (1-\alpha)P+\alpha Q)$  a monotone increasing function of $\alpha$ for $0\le\alpha\le 1$?

My numerical simulations seem to suggest so, but is this a well-known result? Or is there a counterexample?

Comment: This will follow from just taking a derivative in $\alpha$. I'll try to think of something more elegant, but if you're only interested in the answer, try the following - write out the expanded expression, and with some manipulation you'/ll get a sum of the form $\sum_\mathcal{X} P_x\log P_x - \left( (2 - \alpha)P_x + \alpha Q_x \right)\log \left((1-\alpha/2) P_x + (\alpha/2)Q_x \right) + (\alpha Q_x + \bar{\alpha} P_x) \log (\alpha Q_x + \bar{\alpha} P_x) $

Comment: (contd.) which is dirty but workable. Term by term differentiation yields $f'(\alpha) = \sum (Q_x-P_x) \log \frac{(\alpha Q_x + (1 - \alpha) P_x)}{\left((1-\alpha/2) P_x + (\alpha/2)Q_x \right)}$, and it's easy to show that each term in this sum is non-negative - $Q_x - P_x \ge 0$ implies the expression in the log is $\ge 1$ and vice versa.